# Expand and collapse animation on LinearLayout with weights

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-linearlayout

Hi i have designed a linear layout like below :

```
<Linear Layout 1 > -- > weightSum = 100
 <Linear Layout 2> -- > weight ->10
 <Linear Layout 3> -- > weight ->10
 <Linear Layout 4> -- > weight ->60
    <listview></listview>
 <Linear Layout 5 > -- > weight ->10
    <Linear Layout> ->visibility GONE
 <Linear Layout 6> -- > weight ->10
</Linear Layout >
```

I have used weights so that the layout height is fixed and not scrollable.

Now i have a to make the `<Linear Layout> whose visibility is GONE to VISIBLE` onclick, here in that case i can reduce the ListView height so that expanding LinearLayout fills properly.

I have used below animation but it shrinks the above view or Linear layout.

```
public static void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int)(targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

Comment: Quickly went through your code so I might be wrong. But the weight sum is 100 and the sum of all visible ViewGroups is also 100. In the animation you aren't playing with the weights and the weight of the newly visible LinearLayout remains 0.

Comment: @VarunSingh Yes you are correct,i need to use something else other than weights so that its height is fixed to different screen layout

Comment: Well according to [Android's guide](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) you should avoid LinearLayout and use RelativeLayout or GridLayout wherever possible. Also if the minSDK >= 11, use [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) instead. Its easier to understand and use.

Comment: @VarunSingh Can we fix the Height of Layout to all screens using Relative layout? like as we do using weights ?

Comment: No I can't think of an obvious way to achieve that. However look into GridLayout. You can specify weight like property using the attribute rowSpan. More about GridLayout [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
v.measure(0, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
```

Comment: No its still the same, it shrinks the above views